# Change background colour for each var in table using AJAX

Tags: ajax, cakephp

I have gone through the various answers provided on Stackflow, however cannot find the answer I need. 
I need to add a different colour for each category that is called in the table. The table uses AJAX in cakePHP. The table calls correctly, but I just need to add a colour for each var.

Here is the code

```
function showTable() {
//var asset = document.getElementById('filter').value;
var startDate = $(".daterange").attr("data-start-date");
var endDate = $(".daterange").attr("data-end-date");
var asset = document.getElementById('assetSelect').value;
var room = document.getElementById('roomSelect').value;
var object = document.getElementById('checkobject');
var person = document.getElementById('checkPerson');
var tools = document.getElementById('checktools');
var filter = '';
```

You can see from above there are 5 different object, I need all the assets to be one colour, all the rooms to be another colour and so forth. 
If you could help I would greatly appreciate it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the style property of your object should do the job :

```
asset.style.background-color = '#f3f3f3';
```